# Avoiding stale (logically corrupt) data when using "ConcurrentDictionary.GetOrAdd()", Repro code included

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety, task-parallel-library

[The bottom of this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997369.aspx) describes how using GetOrAdd may cause (if I understand it correctly) corrupt/unexpected results.

**snip/**

> ConcurrentDictionary is designed for multithreaded
>   scenarios. You do not have to use locks in your code to add or remove
>   items from the collection. However, it is always possible for one
>   thread to retrieve a value, and another thread to immediately update
>   the collection by giving the same key a new value.
>
> Also, although all methods of ConcurrentDictionary are
>   thread-safe, not all methods are atomic, specifically GetOrAdd and
>   AddOrUpdate. The user delegate that is passed to these methods is
>   invoked outside of the dictionary's internal lock. (This is done to
>   prevent unknown code from blocking all threads.) Therefore it is
>   possible for this sequence of events to occur:
>
> 1) threadA calls GetOrAdd, finds no item and creates a new item to Add
>   by invoking the valueFactory delegate.
>
> 2) threadB calls GetOrAdd concurrently, its valueFactory delegate is
>   invoked and it arrives at the internal lock before threadA, and so its
>   new key-value pair is added to the dictionary.
>
> 3) threadA's user delegate completes, and the thread arrives at the
>   lock, but now sees that the item exists already
>
> 4) threadA performs a "Get", and returns the data that was previously
>   added by threadB.
>
> Therefore, it is not guaranteed that the data that is returned by
>   GetOrAdd is the same data that was created by the thread's
>   valueFactory. A similar sequence of events can occur when AddOrUpdate
>   is called.

**Question**

What is the correct way to verify the data, and retry the update?  A nice approach would be an extension method to try/retry this operation based on the contents of old value.

How would this be implemented? Can I rely on the result (`verify`) as a valid-end-state, or must I retry and re-retrieve the values using a different method?

**Code**

The following code has a race condition when updating the values.  The desired behavior is that AddOrUpdateWithoutRetrieving() will increment various values in different ways (using `++` or `Interlocked.Increment()`).

I also want to perform multiple field operations in a single unit and retry the update if the previous update didn't "take" due to a race condition.

Run the code and you will see each value appear in the console start out increasing by one, but each of the values will drift and some will be a few iterations ahead/behind.

```
namespace DictionaryHowTo
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Concurrent;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    // The type of the Value to store in the dictionary:
    class FilterConcurrentDuplicate
    {
        // Create a new concurrent dictionary.
        readonly ConcurrentDictionary<int, TestData> eventLogCache = 
             new ConcurrentDictionary<int, TestData>();

        static void Main()
        {
            FilterConcurrentDuplicate c = new FilterConcurrentDuplicate();

            c.DoRace(null);
        }

        readonly ConcurrentDictionary<int, TestData> concurrentCache = 
            new ConcurrentDictionary<int, TestData>();
        void DoRace(string[] args)
        {
            int max = 1000;

            // Add some key/value pairs from multiple threads.
            Task[] tasks = new Task[3];

            tasks[0] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {

                System.Random RandNum = new System.Random();
                int MyRandomNumber = RandNum.Next(1, 500);

                Thread.Sleep(MyRandomNumber);
                AddOrUpdateWithoutRetrieving();

            });

            tasks[1] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                System.Random RandNum = new System.Random();
                int MyRandomNumber = RandNum.Next(1, 1000);

                Thread.Sleep(MyRandomNumber);

                AddOrUpdateWithoutRetrieving();

            });

            tasks[2] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                AddOrUpdateWithoutRetrieving();

            });
            // Output results so far.
            Task.WaitAll(tasks);

            AddOrUpdateWithoutRetrieving();

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        public class TestData : IEqualityComparer<TestData>
        {
            public string aStr1 { get; set; }
            public Guid? aGud1 { get; set; }
            public string aStr2 { get; set; }
            public int aInt1 { get; set; }
            public long? aLong1 { get; set; }

            public DateTime aDate1 { get; set; }
            public DateTime? aDate2 { get; set; }

            //public int QueryCount { get; set; }
            public int QueryCount = 0;//

            public string zData { get; set; }
            public bool Equals(TestData x, TestData y)
            {
                return x.aStr1 == y.aStr1 &&
                    x.aStr2 == y.aStr2 &&
                       x.aGud1 == y.aGud1 &&
                       x.aStr2 == y.aStr2 &&
                       x.aInt1 == y.aInt1 &&
                       x.aLong1 == y.aLong1 &&
                       x.aDate1 == y.aDate1 &&
                       x.QueryCount == y.QueryCount ;
            }

            public int GetHashCode(TestData obj)
            {
                TestData ci = (TestData)obj;
                // http://stackoverflow.com/a/263416/328397
                return 
                  new { 
                         A = ci.aStr1, 
                         Aa = ci.aStr2, 
                         B = ci.aGud1, 
                         C = ci.aStr2, 
                         D = ci.aInt1, 
                         E = ci.aLong1, 
                         F = ci.QueryCount , 
                         G = ci.aDate1}.GetHashCode();
            }
        }
        private   void AddOrUpdateWithoutRetrieving()
        {
            // Sometime later. We receive new data from some source.
            TestData ci = new TestData() 
            { 
              aStr1 = "Austin", 
              aGud1 = new Guid(), 
              aStr2 = "System", 
              aLong1 = 100, 
              aInt1 = 1000, 
              QueryCount = 0, 
              aDate1 = DateTime.MinValue
            };

            TestData verify = concurrentCache.AddOrUpdate(123, ci,
                (key, existingVal) =>
                {
                    existingVal.aStr2 = "test1" + existingVal.QueryCount;
                    existingVal.aDate1 = DateTime.MinValue;
                    Console.WriteLine
                     ("Thread:" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + 
                          "  Query Count A:" + existingVal.QueryCount);
                    Interlocked.Increment(ref existingVal.QueryCount);
                    System.Random RandNum = new System.Random();
                    int MyRandomNumber = RandNum.Next(1, 1000);

                    Thread.Sleep(MyRandomNumber);
                    existingVal.aInt1++;
                    existingVal.aDate1 = 
                         existingVal.aDate1.AddSeconds
                         (existingVal.aInt1);  
                    Console.WriteLine(
                          "Thread:" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + 
                           "  Query Count B:" + existingVal.QueryCount);
                    return existingVal;
                });


            // After each run, every value here should be ++ the previous value
            Console.WriteLine(
                "Thread:"+Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + 
                 ": Query Count returned:" + verify.QueryCount + 
                 " eid:" + verify.aInt1 + " date:" +  
                 verify.aDate1.Hour + " "  + verify.aDate1.Second + 
                 " NAME:" + verify.aStr2
                );
        }

    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Thread:12: Query Count returned:0 eid:1000 date:0 0 NAME:System

Thread:12  Query Count A:0
Thread:13  Query Count A:1
Thread:12  Query Count B:2
Thread:12: Query Count returned:2 eid:1001 date:0 41 NAME:test11

Thread:12  Query Count A:2
Thread:13  Query Count B:3
Thread:13: Query Count returned:3 eid:1002 date:0 42 NAME:test12

Thread:13  Query Count A:3
Thread:11  Query Count A:4
Thread:11  Query Count B:5
Thread:11: Query Count returned:5 eid:1003 date:0 43 NAME:test14

Thread:11  Query Count A:5
Thread:13  Query Count B:6
Thread:13: Query Count returned:6 eid:1004 date:0 44 NAME:test15
```

....

```
Thread:11  Query Count A:658
Thread:11  Query Count B:659
Thread:11: Query Count returned:659 eid:1656 date:0 36 NAME:test1658

Thread:11  Query Count A:659
Thread:11  Query Count B:660
Thread:11: Query Count returned:660 eid:1657 date:0 37 NAME:test1659

Thread:11  Query Count A:660
Thread:11  Query Count B:661
Thread:11: Query Count returned:661 eid:1658 date:0 38 NAME:test1660

Thread:11  Query Count A:661
Thread:11  Query Count B:662
Thread:11: Query Count returned:662 eid:1659 date:0 39 NAME:test1661
```

In this code "eid" should always be 1,000 more than Query count, but over the iterations the difference varies from 1 to 7 between the two.  That inconsistency may cause some applications to fail or report incorrect data.

Comment: `ConcurrentDictionary` is only thread-safe with regard to its own invariants.  i.e. it won't corrupt its own data.  If you have other invariants, it can't possibly know about them beforehand or be expected to compensate for them.  You need to coherently define what your invariant is and protect is as a transaction with some sort of threading synchronization.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This submission is based on an incorrect understanding of the remarks at the bottom of the article “*How to: Add and Remove Items from a ConcurrentDictionary*” http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997369.aspx and on a basic concurrency bug – concurrent non-atomic modification of a shared object.

First, let’s clarify what the linked article really says. I’ll use `AddOrUpdate` as example, but the reasoning for `GetOrAdd` is equivalent.

Say, you call `AddOrUpdate` from several threads and specify the same key. Assume that an entry with that key already exists.
Each thread will come along, notice that there is already an entry with the specified key and that the Update part of `AddOrUpdate` is relevant.
In doing so, no thread will lock the dictionary. Instead it will use some interlocked instructions to atomically check if an entry-key exists or not.

So, our several threads all noticed that the key exists and that the `updateValueFactory` needs to be called. That delegate is passed to `AddOrUpdate`; it takes references the existing key and value and returns the update-value. Now, all the threads involved will call the factory concurrently. Then they will all complete in some previously unknown order and every thread will try using an atomic operation (using interlocked instructions) to replace the existing value with the value it just computed. There is no way to know which thread will “win”. The thread that wins will get to store its computed value. Others will notice that the value in the dictionary is no longer the value that was passed into their `updateValueFactory` as an argument. In response to that realisation, they will abandon the operation and throw away the just computed value. This is exactly what you want to happen.

Next, lets clarify why you get strange values when running the code sample listed here:

Recall that the `updateValueFactory` delegate passed to `AddOrUpdate` takes REFERENCES the existing key and value and returns the update-value.
The code sample in its `AddOrUpdateWithoutRetrieving()` method starts performing operations directly o that reference. Instead of creating a new replacement value and modifying THAT, it modifies instance member values of `existingVal` – an object that is already in the dictionary – and then simply returns that reference. And it does that not atomically – it reads some values, updates some values, reads more, updates more. Of course, we have seen above that this happens on several threads concurrently – they all modify the SAME object. No wonder the result is that at any one time (when the code sample calls `WriteLine`), the object contains member instance values that originated from different threads.

The dictionary has nothing to do with this – the code simply modifies an object that is shared between threads non-atomically. This is one of the most common concurrency bugs around. The two most common workarounds depend on the scenario. Either use a shared lock to make the entire object modification atomic, or first atomically copy the entire object and then modify the local copy.

For the latter, try adding this to the `TestData` class:

```
private Object _copyLock = null;
 
private Object GetLock() {
 
    if (_copyLock != null)
        return _copyLock;
 
    Object newLock = new Object();
    Object prevLock = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _copyLock, newLock, null);
    return (prevLock == null) ? newLock : prevLock;
}
 
public TestData Copy() {
 
    lock (GetLock()) {
        TestData copy = new TestData();
        copy.aStr1 = this.aStr1;
        copy.aStr2 = this.aStr2;
        copy.aLong1 = this.aLong1;
        copy.aInt1 = this.aInt1;
        copy.QueryCount = this.QueryCount;
        copy.aDate1 = this.aDate1;
        copy.aDate2 = this.aDate2;
        copy.zData = this.zData;
 
        return copy;
    }
}
```

Then modify the factory as follows:

```
TestData verify = concurrentCache.AddOrUpdate(123, ci,
    (key, existingVal) =>
    {
        TestData newVal = existingVal.Copy();
        newVal.aStr2 = "test1" + newVal.QueryCount;
        newVal.aDate1 = DateTime.MinValue;
        Console.WriteLine("Thread:" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + "  Query Count A:" + newVal.QueryCount);
        Interlocked.Increment(ref newVal.QueryCount);
        System.Random RandNum = new System.Random();
        int MyRandomNumber = RandNum.Next(1, 1000);
 
        Thread.Sleep(MyRandomNumber);
        newVal.aInt1++;
        newVal.aDate1 = newVal.aDate1.AddSeconds(newVal.aInt1);
        Console.WriteLine("Thread:" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + "  Query Count B:" + newVal.QueryCount);
        return newVal;
    });
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: *"Instead it will use some interlocked instructions to atomically check if an entry-key exists or not."* -- Maybe this was the case when this answer was written, but currently (.NET 7) the `ConcurrentDictionary` is using `volatile` fields and the `Volatile` class, not the `Interlocked` class, in read operations like the `TryGetValue` method ([source code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/ca584ef0160c1806c91f2edf544de7070958ff55/src/libraries/System.Collections.Concurrent/src/System/Collections/Concurrent/ConcurrentDictionary.cs#L466)).

Answer (score 3):

Probably the correct way is to not care if the returned value is not the one being created by the `valueFactory`. If this is not acceptable, you need to use a lock.

Comment: See the attached code... I think a C# extension method is needed to try...retry the update until it's consistent.  That or incorporate a spinlock.  Not caring isn't the answer IMO

Comment: As long as the valueFactory has no side effects (which is most likely a good idea), it should usually not matter.

Answer (score 2):

There is no general protection that always works. But a common workaround is to return a `Lazy<T>` instead of a `T`. That way creating unneeded lazy's does no harm because the won't ever be started. Only one Lazy will make it to be the final value corresponding to the key. Only one particular Lazy instance will ever be returned.

Comment: Do you know how I can implement this in an extension method that addresses the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Use the following method [written by Stephen Toub](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/building-a-custom-getoradd-method-for-concurrentdictionarytkeytvalue/):

```cs
    static TValue GetOrAdd<TKey, TValue>(
        this ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary,
        TKey key, Func<TKey, TValue> valueFactory,
        out bool added) where TKey : notnull
    {
        TValue factoryValue = default!;
        var factoryValueCreated = false;
        while (true)
        {
            if (dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out var value))
            {
                added = false;
                return value;
            }

            if (!factoryValueCreated)
            {
                factoryValue = valueFactory(key);
                factoryValueCreated = true;
            }

            if (dictionary.TryAdd(key, factoryValue))
            {
                added = true;
                return factoryValue;
            }
        }
    }
```

Note that even here the factory can be called without having its result added to the dictionary. But you would get an indication of what happened.

Comment: Yes, an extension function that wraps GetOrAdd is what I'm looking for.  I'm having troubles creating an overload that automatically retries the GetOrAdd if the corruption occurs.